# Data preprocessing with apache spark and scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm pretty new to spark and scala and therefore I have some questions concerning data preprocessing with spark and working with rdds.
I'm working on a little project and I want to implement a machine learning system with spark. Working with the algorithms is ok I think but I have problems with preprocessing the data. 
I have a dataset with 30 columns and about one million rows. But for simplicity lets assume I have the following dataset (csv-file):

```
columnA, columnB, column_txt, label
1      , a      , abc       , 0
2      ,        , abc       , 0
3      , b      , abc       , 1
4      , b      , abc       , 1
5      , a      , abc       , 0
6      ,        , abc       , 0
7      , c      , abc       , 1
8      , a      , abc       , 1
9      , b      , abc       , 1
10     , c      , abc       , 0
```

After loading the data in spark I want to do the following steps:

1. Remove all columns that end with "_txt"
2. Filter out all rows where columnB is empty (this I figured out already)
3. Delete those columns that have more than 9 levels (here columnA)

So I have problems with issue 1. and 3.
I know I can't remove columns so I have to create a new rdd but how do I do that without certain columns?
For now I'm loading the csv file without a header in spark but for my tasks I need to. Is it recommendable to load the header in a separate rdd? But how can I interact with that rdd to find the right columns then?
Sorry, I know lots of questions but I'm still at the beginning and trying to learn.
Thanks and best regards,
Chris

Comment: If I were doing this "by hand" I would create an RDD, call `.take(1)` on it to get the headers in the master, do whatever processing/parallelizing I needed to with the headers, and then drop the first row to get the data in the RDD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming data frame is loaded with headers and structure is flat:

```
val df = sqlContext.
    read.
    format("com.databricks.spark.csv").
    option("header", "true").
    load("data.csv")
```

something like this should work:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

def moreThan9(df: DataFrame, col: String) = {
    df.agg(countDistinct(col)).first()(0) match {
        case x: Long => x > 9L
        case _ => false
    }
}

val newDf = df.
    schema. //  Extract schema
    toArray. // Convert to array
    map(_.name). // Map to names
    foldLeft(df)((df: DataFrame, col: String) => {
        if (col.endsWith("_txt") | moreThan9(df, col)) df.drop(col) else df
    })
```

If it is loaded without header then you can do the same thing using mapping from automatically the assigned ones to the actual.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I will try it within the next few days.

Comment: Why foldLeft and not filter?

Comment: @dskrvk Do you mean something like `.filter(...).foreach(col => df = df.drop(col))`? Simply a matter of referential transparency and a personal taste I guess.